# Echo Information One Line Under FINDSTR Result

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I am not sure if this is easily possible.  I can easily parse any line that contains the same information.  If I wanted to find all the lines that contain billing info in test.txt I could do `findstr /c:"Billing" test.txt`

But what if I wanted the line after the `findstr` result. In this example I would like to try and find the user notes but they are on the line below.

Edit:
The random strings are exactly that.  They contain no similar characters.  Also the actual file contains hundreds of lines not only the four I have included as an example.

```
Billing Info 1234
PayPal Manage Payment
User Notes:
ABC  RANDOM STRING
 
Billing Info 5678
PayPal Manage Payment
User Notes:
DEF RANDOM STRING

Billing Info qwerty
PayPal Manage Payment
User Notes:
XYZ RANDOM STRING
```

I thought something could be done with a `for loop` and the `skip` flag.

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1*" %a in ('findstr /c:"User" test.txt') do (echo %a %b)
```

But I think `skip` skips lines at the start of file rather than at each result.

Apologies if this is painfully obvious, thank you for any help or advice.

Rory

Comment: Edit: The random strings are exactly that. They contain no similar characters. Sorry.  Your second idea is nice but they are hundreds of lines in the actual file, I just tried to simplify.  That you for your reply though.

Comment: So you want every line that appears immediately below `User Notes:`, right? And the user notes to extract always consist of a single line, correct?

Answer (score 2):

**FINDSTR** cannot be used here as it always processes a text file line by line. It is not possible to search for a line below another line or instruct **FINDSTR** to output additional lines below or above a line containing a found string.

The following batch file code may work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "test.txt" exit /B 1
set "UserNotes="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in ("test.txt") do for /F tokens^=1^,2^ eol^= %%I in ("%%#") do (
    if "%%I %%J" == "Billing Info" (
        set "UserNotes="
    ) else if "%%I %%J" == "User Notes:" (
        set "UserNotes=1"
    ) else if defined UserNotes (
        echo(%%#
    )
)
endlocal
```

The outer **FOR /F** loop processes the text file with ignoring only empty lines. Each non-empty line is assigned as is to the specified loop variable `#` because of the definition of an empty list of delimiters and no end of line character. The syntax without usage of surrounding `"` must be used here as this is the only possibility to specify no delimiter and no end of line character.

The inner **FOR /F** loop processes the current line by splitting the line up into substrings (tokens) with using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. The end of line character is again defined with no character as the user note to output could start also with a semicolon after zero or more leading spaces/tabs which should not be ignored by the inner **FOR /F** loop. Just the first two space/tab separated strings are of interest and are assigned therefore to the loop variables `I` and `J`.

The first **IF** condition is true on current line starting with the two words which indicate that a new data block begins which means the user notes section of previous data block ends. The environment variable `UserNotes` is deleted in this case.

The second **IF** condition is true on current line starting with the two words which indicate that next the user notes follow. For that reason the environment variable `UserNotes` is defined with a value. The value itself does not matter.

The third **IF** condition is true only if the other two **IF** conditions are false and the environment variable `UserNotes` is defined at the moment. In this case a non-empty line with user notes is currently assigned by the outer **FOR /F** to the loop variable `#` which is output now (or further processed).

There is used `echo(%%#` instead of `echo %%#` to output correct also a user note line which contains only spaces/tabs and nothing else (blank but not empty line). The usage of `echo %%#` would result in this case in output of current state of the command echo mode. The usage of `(` as delimiter between the command **ECHO** and the non-empty line to output prevents the output of the state of the command echo mode on blank line to output.

The following batch file can be used if all user notes should be written into a text file like `UserNotes.txt` in current directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "test.txt" exit /B 1
set "UserNotes="
(for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%# in ("test.txt") do for /F tokens^=1^,2^ eol^= %%I in ("%%#") do (
    if "%%I %%J" == "Billing Info" (
        set "UserNotes="
    ) else if "%%I %%J" == "User Notes:" (
        set "UserNotes=1"
    ) else if defined UserNotes (
        echo(%%#
    )
))>"UserNotes.txt"
if exist "UserNotes.txt" for %%I in ("UserNotes.txt") do if %%~zI == 0 del "UserNotes.txt"
endlocal
```

The file `UserNotes.txt` is deleted on being created before, but nothing is output into this file.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`